# walker nav mega menu

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Please help me,
I'm making an online shopping site using wordpress themes, I get a problem to make the mega menu, I have the following html code.
I've tried with nav walker from other sources, but the results are not in accordance with the html code that I created.

```
<div class="mega-categories">    
<ul class="mega-list">
  <li class="mega-sub-menu">
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
         <div class="mega-menu-page">
           <div class="mega-page-list col-md-3">
             <ul class="mega-sub-list">
             <li><a href="#">page link 1</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 1</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
             <li><a href="#">page link 2</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             </ul>
           </div>

           <div class="mega-page-list col-md-3">
             <ul class="mega-sub-list">
             <li><a href="#">page link 3</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">page link 4</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             </ul>
             </div>
          <div class="mega-page-list col-md-3">
             <ul class="mega-sub-list">
             <li><a href="#">page link 5</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">page link 6</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub page link 6</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             </ul>
            </div>
          <div class="mega-page-list col-md-3">
             <ul class="mega-sub-list">
             <li><a href="#">
                 <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/vertical-banner-1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></a></li>
             </ul> 
             </div>  
       </div>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: the problem is how to make wp nav walker, I've tried with this walker nav code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress it is very easy for creating the Mega Menu with the help of the plugin called Megamenu : https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/.
It will save enormous amount of time if you create Mega menu with the help of this Plugin

Answer (score 0):

the problem is how to make wp nav walker, I've tried with this walker nav code

```html
<?php
$megamenu = 0;
$count=0;
class nav_walker_megamenu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
      public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
             $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
             if($depth == 0) $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"mega-menu-page\">
                                           $indent<ul class=\"mega-sub-list\">\n"; 
                        else $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }

      public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if($depth == 0) $output .= "$indent</ul>\n                                     
                                    $indent</div>\n";
                   else $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";

    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $megamenu;
        $megamenu++;
        global $count;
        $count++;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $class_names = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
  
if ($megamenu == 4) {
            $output .= "\n$indent</ul>$indent<ul class=\"drop-dow\">\n";
            $megamenu = 1;

        }

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );

        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';


        $output .= $indent .  '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();

        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';

        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        if ($item->menu_item_parent == 0) $megamenu = 0;
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before .apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        if ($megamenu == 4) $megamenu = 0;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

    }
} // Walker_Nav_Menu
```

with code nav walker out these results are not in accordance with the html code that I created above.